# QGIS - Issue importing CSV Table (owner information) with quotation marks

Tags: qgis, csv, import, table

When importing my CSV table into QGIS, rows containing quotes are not correctly separated into columns. Is it possible to define the column separator to tolerate quotes or is there another problem?

[image: Teabelle]

[image: screenshot of importissue]

```
flstkennz,amtsgericht,grundbuchbezirk,gbbz,blatt,lfdnrbestandsvz,buchungsart,miteigentumsanteil,artrechtsgemeinschaft,anteileigentuemer,eigentuemer,vorname,geburtsname,geburtsdatum,strassehausnummer,plz,ort,"herkunft;"
126548165498____,Neuruppin,Breddin,100000,111,11,Grundstück,,,,Joen Doe e.G,,,,Doe Straße 6,11111,Manchester,"Kataster;"
"12300800100854______,Neuruppin,Breddin,100000,0000222,0001,Grundstück,,,,""Test GmbH """"Testeinrichtungen und -pflege"""""",,,,Nudelpromenade 4,22222,Bagdad,Kataster;",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
128728037001430026__,Perleberg,Wittenberge,100008,1,1,Miteigentum Par. 8 Abs. 2 GBO,Jan 28,,01.04.2023,Peter,Kloeppel,Anders,11111911,Granatenweg 99,99322,Tokio,"Kataster;"
"12302001300768______,Neuruppin,Dreetz,100000,0004386,0009,Grundstück,,,,Frank,Beckenbauer,D. Soost,24.12.1965,Ums Eck 3,12345,""Waterloo,"",Grundbuch;",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Please try to create a minimal example that exibits your problem and also please try to add data as copyable data and not as a screenshot.

Comment: has nobody a hint? or is somthing with my setting that i don't get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your dataset: in the import dialog, check the box `Custom delimiters`, check `Comma` and set `Quote` to `"` and make sure `Escape` is empty:

[image]

Comment: you made my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

When I use this test file as comma.csv

```
name,lat,lon
"Lrrr, ruler of Omicron Persei 8",52,9
Mister Bean,11,8
"try,,,,,,,,,,this at home",59,13
```

and these import options

[image: import options for csv]

Everything loads correctly:

[image: result, all points labeled as expected]

edit:

your CSV input has multiple issues. I took your data, pasted the one line into notepad++, stretched the app over both monitors and then manually aligned the commas.

```
flstkennz            ,amtsgericht,grundbuchbezirk,gbbz  ,blatt  ,lfdnrbestandsvz,buchungsart                  ,miteigentumsanteil,artrechtsgemeinschaft,anteileigentuemer,eigentuemer                                        ,vorname     ,geburtsname,geburtsdatum,strassehausnummer,plz  ,ort          ,"herkunft;"
126548165498____     ,Neuruppin  ,Breddin        ,100000,111    ,11             ,Grundstück                   ,                  ,                     ,                 ,Joen Doe e.G                                       ,            ,           ,            ,Doe Straße 6     ,11111,Manchester   ,"Kataster;"
"12300800100854______,Neuruppin  ,Breddin        ,100000,0000222,0001           ,Grundstück                   ,                  ,                     ,                 ,""Test GmbH """"Testeinrichtungen und -pflege"""""",            ,           ,            ,Nudelpromenade 4 ,22222,Bagdad       ,Kataster;"
                     ,           ,               ,      ,       ,               ,                             ,                  ,                     ,                 ,                                                   ,            ,           ,            ,                 ,     ,             ,
128728037001430026__ ,Perleberg  ,Wittenberge    ,100008,1      ,1              ,Miteigentum Par. 8 Abs. 2 GBO,Jan 28            ,                     ,01.04.2023       ,Peter                                              ,Kloeppel    ,Anders     ,11111911    ,Granatenweg 99   ,99322,Tokio        ,"Kataster;"
"12302001300768______,Neuruppin  ,Dreetz         ,100000,0004386,0009           ,Grundstück                   ,                  ,                     ,                 ,Frank                                              ,Beckenbauer ,D. Soost   ,24.12.1965  ,Ums Eck 3        ,12345,""Waterloo,"",Grundbuch;"
                     ,           ,               ,      ,       ,               ,                             ,                  ,                     ,                 ,                                                   ,            ,           ,            ,                 ,     ,             ,
```

First, there were no linebreaks in your data. That may be a problem of copy-pasting the data to Stackoverflow.

Second, there is an issue with line 3 starting with "1230". The quote is never closed in the field, so technically the flstkennz runs all the way up to the end of the eigentuemer string (because double quotes are escaped quotes, see https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html ). Line 6 has the same issue.

Third, it is unclear what the desired string should be for eigentuemer of line 3. Should it be `Test GmbH "Testeinrichungen und -pflege"`?

ort has also doubled quotes, which is not supported by the GDAL CSV driver. The string `"Waterloo,"` should be `"""Waterloo,"""` in the CSV.

Is `Jan 28` a correct value for miteigentumsanteil? It seems weird. Same goes for `01.04.2023` in anteileigentuemer.

Maybe this example shows the behaviour of quotes. It imports correctly to QGIS:

```
name,lat,lon,"extra field;.,"
"Lrrr, ruler of ""Omicron Persei"" 8",52,9,
Mister Bean,11,8,
"try,,,,,,,,,,this at home",59,13,"totally extra;"
"""never"" try ""this"" at ""home""",51,22,
```

[image: csv qith quotes, attribute table shown]

Do you create the CSV yourself? Then you can fix the issues yourself. If you consume the CSV that is created elsewhere then ask that person to fix the CSV.

Comment: try setting the quotation marks later (after a comma). the comma characters are seperators. In my case it'S not working...

https://imgur.com/a/ar1cLiD

Comment: Hello til_b, thanks for your observation and answer. the data (40tsd lines) is as I've received it. i had to change content because of data privacy and yes, i had no clue how to copy the csv data into stackoverflow, so maybe the linebreaks got lost... I think the quotation marks are used as paragraphs in the data providing  authority. so when you have """Frank Walther" "Seseamstraße" "Cottbus""" it might indicate a linebreak in the origin system... But that is only an assumption. 
Nevertheless @Babel provided the answer I was looking for. It's a solution for my problem with this data :)